# Firebase authentication in IPC main and renderer processes

Tags: node.js, firebase, electron

I've been working on an app that uses Electron with both NodeJS and jQuery, Bootstrap and Firebase. I've encountered many issues with development.

The first issue is the FirebaseUI, which works in Electron by embedding it into the HTML (Firebase's CDN), but not with node dependencies.

The second issue I've encountered is bad performance when the main process is receiving a large dataset from Firestore; I've initialized the firebase in the
**Main process**, parsed the object to the renderer process and put an onSnapshotListener to a collection to keep my data in sync, which heavily impacted my performance (30s to load the page).

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 1000,
    webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: true,
        nodeIntegration: true,
        nativeWindowOpen: true
    },
});
let details = {/*init info*/};
firebase.initializeApp(details);
global.firebase = firebase; //to access the firebase instance from the renderer process
mainWindow.loadFile('source/login/login.html'); //load login window
mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null;
});
```

So I've resorted to initialize my app in each renderer process (which works well with onSnapshotListener), but I should've always authenticate the user when the user changes a page.

```
const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.initializeApp(require('electron').remote.getGlobal('firebaseLoginDetails'));
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

Is there a better way to solve both performance and authentication problems?

Comment: Just how big is your data set? You should paginate your results. Make sure your communicating asynchronously with the main thread ipcMain. Actually the renderer process is the preferred way of communication with firebase. See https://medium.com/firebase-developers/using-firebase-in-electron-tips-and-tricks-24ac5b44bf5a

Comment: My dataset has about 200-300 entries at the time. I'll paginate later, I just want to finish my core functionalities first. How exactly would I do that?

Comment: I've used both Firebase and Electron extensively but never Firebase together with Electron. You should read the article there are some issues.

Comment: I've come across this article when I was trying to fix the gRPC issue. One thing I didn't mention is I have a rendered process for each page, which might not be the most ideal thing, but keeps my code somewhat sorted.